# Prefered method to map a remote filesystem in windows?

Tags: windows, filesystems, webdav

For a current project, I need to allow users to access their files remotely from Windows. I'm looking for a solution with an explorer integration (using Shell Namespace Extensions).

I first try using WebDAV and the built-in client in Windows but the client is not of equal quality in all Windows version and adding SSL and/or authentication is not working as espected.

I am not attached to WebDAV, it can be any protocol. I prefer open-source project or a commercial one with a SDK license (must be integrated in a product).

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried "sharing" the filesystem? If your server runs Linux, you could try [samba](http://www.samba.org/). I haven't tried Windows in a while, but I seem to remember that the Explorer did ftp as well.

I'm assuming plain HTTP is a no go here.